# Deserializer for List[T] types

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a `JsArray` into a `List[T]` in a playframework application using Scala. After some research I found this method which is supposed to do the needed work:

```
/**
 * Deserializer for List[T] types.
 */
implicit def listReads[T](implicit fmt: Reads[T]): Reads[List[T]] = new Reads[List[T]] {
  def reads(json: JsValue) = json match {
    case JsArray(ts) => ts.map(t => fromJson(t)(fmt)).toList
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("List expected")
  }
}
```

The problem is that I didn't know how to use it. Any help is welcome.

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that this is the solution to your problem, if you don't know how it works?  What's the fully-qualified classname of `Reads`, is it one of your own classes or a class from a library?

Comment: `Reads` is a class from a library used to convert your `JsValue` into a `T`object([Format](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.1/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Format)). This is were i find the exemple([Here](http://xuwei-k.github.com/play-sxr/play-2.9.1-2.0/play/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick example:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> Json.toJson(List(1, 2, 3)).as[List[Int]]
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

And if you have a custom type with a `Format` instance:

```
case class Foo(i: Int, x: String)

implicit object fooFormat extends Format[Foo] {
  def reads(json: JsValue) = Foo(
    (json \ "i").as[Int],
    (json \ "x").as[String]
  )
  def writes(foo: Foo) = JsObject(Seq(
    "i" -> JsNumber(foo.i),
    "x" -> JsString(foo.x)
  ))
 }
```

It still works:

```
scala> val foos = Foo(1, "a") :: Foo(2, "bb") :: Nil
foos: List[Foo] = List(Foo(1,a), Foo(2,bb))

scala> val json = Json.toJson(foos)
json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [{"i":1,"x":"a"},{"i":2,"x":"bb"}]

scala> json.as[List[Foo]]
res1: List[Foo] = List(Foo(1,a), Foo(2,bb))
```

This approach would also work if your custom type had a `xs: List[String]` member, for example: you'd just use `(json \ "xs").as[List[String]]` in your `reads` method and `Json.toJson(foo.xs)` in your `writes`.

Comment: Thank you it worked. i didn't think about using my Format instance that way.this is good to know.